# Cocos2D pauseAllRunningActions?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, target, resume, onpause

I am having a hard time resuming animations in my Cocos2D app. I add a CCSprite as a child to a CCSpriteBatchNode and it goes off on an animation.

So when I click the pause button I do this:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] actionManager] pauseAllRunningActions];
```

Now in the docs they say to use:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] actionManager] resumeTargets:];
```

However, I have tried every possible target including the sprite itself, the batchnode, self (CCLayer), and the current CCScene and nothing has worked.

Is there some sort of way to resume ***ALL Targets?***

**Edit:** I declared an NSSet in a Singleton and I do this:

```
[Singleton sharedSingleton].pauseTargets = [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] actionManager] pauseAllRunningActions];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] actionManager] pauseAllRunningActions];
```

Then to resume I do:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] actionManager] resumeTargets:[Singleton sharedSingleton].pauseTargets];
```

But I get a crash:

```
2012-08-29 18:40:05.433 App[34872:707] -[__NSMallocBlock__ countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e075a40
2012-08-29 18:40:05.434 App[34872:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSMallocBlock__ countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e075a40'
```

Comment: Have you tried `[[CCDirector sharedDirector]pause]` and `[[CCDirector sharedDirector]resume]`?

Comment: No I can't do that. Otherwise my pause layer won't be added as a child.

Comment: Do you want your scene frozen, or it should be animating while on pause?

Comment: The scene should NOT be frozen, I just want ALL currently animating things in the scene to be paused and resumed successfully. The pauseAllRunningActions does exactly that, but I just don't know the Target it is pausing. And there is no resumeAllRunningActions method.

Comment: `- (NSSet *) pauseAllRunningActions`
Pauses all running actions, returning a list of targets whose actions were paused. Hope that helps

Comment: Okay check out my edit. So now that you see what the runningActions are, what do I put for resumeTargets: ?

Comment: To resume these targets pass that returned NSSet in `resumeTargets:` method `[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] actionManager] resumeTargets:theTargets];`

Comment: Check out my Edit2. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15990/discussion-between-urlarenzo-and-ibrad-apps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Stores paused targets**

```
NSSet *pausedTargets = [[NSSet alloc] initWithSet:[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] actionManager] pauseAllRunningActions]];
```

**Resumes paused targets**

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] actionManager] resumeTargets:pausedTargets];
```

Also don't forget to release `pausedTargets` after you unpause.